# How to navigate to custom tab in record page in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
// Navigate to View Account Page
navigateToViewAccountPage() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.recordId,
            objectApiName: 'Account',
            actionName: 'view'
        },
    });
}
```

Currently, I am using the above code. It is navigating to the Detail tab of the record page. But I need to navigate to the custom tab created on the record page.

Is there any way that we can navigate to custom tab on record page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below code should help you to navigate to custom tab

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__navItemPage',
            attributes: {
                apiName: CustomTabApiName
            },
          state: { 
                c__id: this.recordId 
           }
});
```

You can refer [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_page_types) for more details

Comment: Hi Rohit, I have tried this but it is not working. PageNot Exist error is occurring. I need to navigate to the tab we create on the Lightning page not the tab we create from setup

Comment: @Jhony - I have updated my answer above, while passing the recordId, you would need to prefix c__id.

Comment: i would highly encourage you to explain why you are proposing this approach, why the state property, etc,etc, instead of just dumping code as an answer. Thanks